# Idiomatic way to test if no positional params are given?

Tags: bash, parameters, command-line-arguments, idioms, conditional-statements

What is the most idiomatic way in Bash to test if no positional parameters are given? There are so many ways to check this, I wonder if there is one preferred way.

Some ways are:

```
((! $# )) # check if $# is 'not true'
(($# == 0)) # $# is 0
[[ ! $@ ]] # $@ is unset or null
```

Comment: The last one will false positive on `script ''` (null argument).

Comment: IMO you should re-consider what exactly do you consider 'no positional parameters'. For example, do you consider a single null argument (`your-script ''`) a valid argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, the classical way is:

```
[[ $# -eq 0 ]]
```

Comment: +1 but use `[[ ... ]]` instead. `[[ ... ]]` is a bash built-in while `[ ... ]` invokes external test utility. IOW, the former is faster.

Comment: Updated to use `[[ ... ]]`, which is indeed better.

Comment: Actually, `[` is a bash builtin as well (which overrides /bin/[ ), so their speed should be about the same.  The biggest difference is that `[[ ... ]]` avoids some parsing complexity with strings, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: `[[` is not a builtin it is a keyword.  Contrast `type [` with `type [[`.  This means it is interogated earlier in the command-line expansion and why, for example, you don't need to quote variables with embedded spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be an error to have no positional parameters:

```
: ${@?no positional parameters}
```

will print "no positional parameters" to standard error (and exit a non-interactive shell) if `$@` is unset.

Otherwise, I'm not aware of any better options than one of the various methods of checking if `$#` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Sensible Semantics

The key is readability and the intent of your code. Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you probably just want to determine the length of the parameter list.

```
# Is length of parameter list equal to zero?
[ $# -eq 0 ]
```

However, you can certainly use any parameter expansion or comparison operator that expresses the intent of your code. There's no right way to do it, but you certainly may wish to consider whether the semantics of your test are *portable*.

#### Food for Thought

It isn't the conditional expression that's intrinsically important. What's important is *why* you want to know. For example:

```
set -e
foo="$1"
shift

# $2 is now $1 (but only if the line is reached)
echo "$1"
```

In this case, the length of the parameter list is never checked directly. The first parameter is simply assigned (even though it may be unset), and then the shell throws an error and exits when you try to shift the parameter list. This code says "I just expect the parameters to be there; I shouldn't have to check for them explicitly."

The point here is that you need to determine what your code is trying to express, and match the semantics of your tests and conditionals to express that as clearly as you can. There really is no orthogonal answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a most logical way:

```
[ ! $@ ]
```

It is based on a single rule:

```
[ ] # this returns 1
```

Well then,

```
[ ! ] # this returns 0
```

The rest is obvious:
$@ is the special parameter that expands to a list of all positional parameters.

Test:
(It will work even if you throw a couple of empty strings ("" "" "") at it.)

```
if [ ! $@ ]; then
    printf 'Note: No arguments are given.'
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using the fact that if there are no positional parameters, there is also no first parameter:

```
[[ -z $1 ]]
test -z "$1"
[ -z "$1" ]
```

It's just a tiny bit lighter on the reader. Of course it only works when the assumption that the first parameter can't be an empty string is true.

Comment: This fails if the first parameter is the empty string: `foo "" 2`.

Comment: Sure, but since it is my code, I would not use this method if I knew the empty string was a valid parameter.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that this does not test for the presence of positional parameters.

Comment: I think you meant `[ -n "$1" ]`. The -n flag checks that the length of STRING is nonzero.

Comment: It's the same, it only matters how you use the result.