# How can I test whether a positional parameter is set in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I wonder why the test `[[ ! -v 1 ]]` fails no matter if I pass the 1st positional parameter to the function below:

```
shopt -os nounset

function foo {
  echo -n "$FUNCNAME: 1st positional parameter "
  [[ ! -v 1 ]] && echo "is missing." || echo is "\"$1\"."
}
```

I know there are other ways to test but why doesn't this particular test  work?

Comment: AFAIK, `-v` is not an operator that is available with `[[` (at least according to the man page that came with bash 4.1 on my system).  Perhaps you want `[[ -z "$1" ]]` ?  Or do you really need to test for the existence of zero-length positional parameters?

Comment: Try `[[ -v SHELL ]]; echo $?`. `-z` doesn't work here because of `shopt -os nounset`.

Comment: Possibly it doesn't work with integers, using normal variable names like "foo" works.

Comment: @TimFriske `[[ -v SHELL ]]` returns `bash: conditional binary operator expected` and ``bash: syntax error near `SHELL'``.  Ruh roh!

Comment: It is in my bash 4.2 manpage: `-v varname True if the shell variable varname is set (has been assigned a value).`

Comment: @ghoti: I don't receive any error. I'm on Fedora 17 64 bit with `echo $BASH_VERSION` giving me `4.2.39(1)-release`.

Comment: Ah, there we go.  The `-v` operator was added in Bash 4.2. I would be highly surprised if it was dependent on operating system, but I was testing in an older FreeBSD system with bash 4.1, and Mac OSX 10.6 which comes with bash 3.2.

Comment: I think the positional parameters don't qualify as _shell  variables_, that's why -v doesn't work on them

Comment: For me, the check for parameters existence should be done with `$#`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492338/idiomatic-way-to-test-if-no-positional-params-are-given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you want to check if the parameter is unset.

```
has_1() {
  if [[ -z "${1+present}" ]]; then 
    echo "no first param"
  else
    echo "given: $1"
  fi
}
```

The [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${var+word}` will return "word" only if the parameter is *not unset* -- i.e. if you pass an empty string, the function will indicate the first parameter is given.

Comment: Your proposal sounds reasonable because it references the positional parameter by its symbol and avoids `bash` from failing with `shopt -os nounset`. If nobody else can explain why `[[ ! -v 1 ]]` doesn't work I shall consider it as a **bug**.

Comment: apparently, -v doesn't work with positional paramaters: `set -- bar; echo $1; [[ -v 1 ]] || echo no foo`

Comment: from Bash 5.1 it does work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233119/1983854 (feel free to copy into your answer)

Answer (score 4):

Bash 5.1 has a very straight-forward way to do this. As described in the [release notes](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS):

> x. `test -v N' can now test whether or not positional parameter N is set.

So to check if the Nth parameter is set can use either of these:

```
test -v N
```

```
[ -v N ]
```

---

See a very basic example:

```
test -v 1 && echo "1st parameter is set: '$1'"
[ -v 2 ] && echo "2nd parameter is set: '$2'"
```

See some samples:

```
bash-5.1$ bash script.sh ""
1st parameter is set: ''

bash-5.1$ bash script.sh a b
1st parameter is set: 'a'
2nd parameter is set: 'b'

bash-5.1$ bash script.sh ""
1st parameter is set: ''

bash-5.1$ bash script.sh "" bla
1st parameter is set: ''
2nd parameter is set: 'bla'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; then echo 'ok'; else echo '0'; fi
```

Comment: We already had this answer but it got deleted by the author because `$#` only indirectly tests whether the 1st positional parameter is set. Also in his answer he could not explain why `[[ ! -v 1 ]]` fails.

Comment: Neither do I know what means the option `-v` to `test`.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern covers most of the practical use cases:

```sh
[[ -z "${2:-}" ]] && echo "The 2'nd parameter is unset" >&2 && exit 1
```

[Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)